# returning last generated id in SQL server table after insertion even if no insert have been made in mybatis mapper

Tags: java, sql, sql-server, spring, mybatis

I'm using mybatis mapper in java to return last generated id of a table in SQL server after insert statement , with a condition to insert record or not , the problem is that i am getting an id even if no record was inserted ,any idea why?

piece of my code:

In my mapper:

```
<insert id="insertStatment" parameterType="HashMap"
        useGeneratedKeys="true" keyProperty="id">

        IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT TOP 1 1 FROM table
        WITH(NOLOCK) WHERE...)

        INSERT INTO table
        (
        column1,
        column 2
        )
        VALUES
        (
        value1,
        value 2
        )

        <selectKey resultType="int" order="AFTER" keyProperty="id">
            SELECT @@IDENTITY as returnedId
        </selectKey>

    </insert>
```

In my DAO:

```
session.insert("insertStatment", map);
Integer id= (Integer) map.get("id");
```

The problem is even when no insert was made , i am getting an id different from id (auto generated) of my table ,any help?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Do you *really* need a `NOLOCK` for an `EXISTS` query..?

Comment: If you aren't inserting anything, then `@@IDENTITY` should return `NULL`; unless you are also performing an `INSERT` in another scope you haven't told us about? `@@IDENTITY` is not limited to the same scope, so if you are then you would be better off using `SCOPE_IDENTITY`.

Comment: @Larnu Thank you for your reply , i am using exists because i need to check if there is a record for a given ids then i don't want to insert any data , is there any other turn around ?

Comment: I'm not asking about the `EXISTS`, @Elias, I'm asking why is there a `NOLOCK`.

Comment: @Larnu normally is use NOLOCK for any select statement.

Comment: *Why* would ever want to use `NOLOCK` for any `SELECT` statement, @Elias ? You*do* understand the consequences of using that table hint, correct? YOu shoul;d only be using it when *really* needed. I can't see a time where you would really need it in an `EXISTS` subquery unless you have other severe performance issues. And if that's the case, then the `NOLOCK` doesn't solve those performance issues; address the performance issues does. `NOLOCK` isn't a magic "go faster button".

Comment: Have a read of [Bad habits : Putting NOLOCK everywhere](https://www.sentryone.com/blog/aaronbertrand/bad-habits-nolock-everywhere)

Comment: @Larnu sorry i don't have too much experience in sql server and thank you for your help,i will read your referenced title,meanwhile do you think the problem is from using NOLOCK?

Comment: No, I cover off my thought process in my second [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63704983/returning-last-generated-id-in-sql-server-table-after-insertion-even-if-no-inser?noredirect=1#comment112651279_63704983)

Comment: @Larnu ok thank you for your help and clarification

Comment: When `IF NOT EXISTS` returns false, `INSERT` is not executed at all and MyBatis may not handle such case correctly. If you explain what you are trying to achieve (it's unclear because you omitted `WHERE` clause), we might be able to propose an alternative approach. Have you considered using `MERGE` statement?